# How can I generate tags files for latex command for use in Vim?

Tags: vim, latex, ctags

I'm using latex-box and omnicomplete when typing latex in Vim. I find that it can just completes some of latex commands.

How can we generate a tags file of the full basic latex command using ctags, or maybe generate tags file from the packages needed in my latexFile.tex in further ?

Anyone know how to do that ? Or some other solutions ?
Thanks!

Update: There is a post about ctags+latex: http://caffeinatedcode.wordpress.com/2009/11/16/simple-latex-ctags-and-taglist/ (It could be useful.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the vim completion part you can use the 'dictionary' option that specifies the list of files to look for candidates for completion for the i_CTRL-X_CTRL_K.

The next part is to generate those files that you want to refer to in the 'dictionary' option.  For this you can google for the list of all 'built-in' latex commands, and for the additional packages you can whip up a shell script to extract all the defined commands.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps you:
http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/extend.html
See the end of document ("Add the following lines to the $HOME/.ctags or $HOME/ctags.conf file").